# Load html file - and access element ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have loaded a html file and "placed" it inside a div:

```
document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="table.html" ></object>';
```

Works fine, but when I try to get an element by it's ID in the table (from table.html) I get null/undefined.

```
var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); /* Nope! */
```

I guess I am doing it at the wrong time or place somehow. Can you help me please?

Best Regards

Comment: its because your table.html has not been loaded yet. you can move the var table retrieval inside a javascript defined in table.html or use JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with jQuery's built-in AJAX method, `.load()`. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_div_id').load('/filepath/table.html');
    var table = $('#my_table');
    // Other code, presumably :)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will try. I guess your example works only if in the document.ready-function? Otherwise it's no different from mine except the way to load the file.

Comment: Yes. It may be that your browser has a cached version of table.html which doesn't have the element with the ID you're trying to get. Try a hard refresh?